# Using Glimpse in nopCommerce project

Tags: nopcommerce

Currently, I am using nopCommerce project version 3.4 and after seeing how powerful tool Glipmse is for real time giagnostics, I have decided to incorporate it in my nopCommerce project.

But I have a dilemma regarding the fact that since the glimpse need to be installed with the nopCommerce web deploy project, this may cause double work of reinstalling it again if a nopCommerce update to the latest version will be installed on the nopCommerce project. This will eventually overriden the glimpse installation.

Ideally I would like a way where I can install Glimpse without modifying the actual source code of NopCommerce so that when a new upgrade is released, we can simply overwrite the entire contents of NopCommerce with the new release and not having to re-install such tools again.

I appreciate any help suggesting any other alternatives on how glimpse can be incorporated with nopCommerce project.

Thanks for any help.